# Duplicate Entry on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I seem to get duplicate entry or Integrity error when trying to create or update my entries  . I have tried using objects.get_or_create() and objects.update_or_create(). Creating seems to work well when there is no record yet but somehow updating is just throwing some duplicate entry error.

here is my views.py:

```python
def evaluate(request):
    r = []
    i = []
    a = []
    s = []
    e = []
    c = []

    for id in range(1,43):
        score = float(request.POST.get(f'{id}'))
        question = RIASEC_Test.objects.get(pk=id)

        if question.category == 'R':
            r.append(score)
        if question.category == 'I':
            i.append(score)
        if question.category == 'A':
            a.append(score)
        if question.category == 'S':
            s.append(score)
        if question.category == 'E':
            e.append(score)
        if question.category == 'C':
            c.append(score)

    r = (sum(r)/7) * 100
    i = (sum(i)/7) * 100
    a = (sum(a)/7) * 100
    s = (sum(s)/7) * 100
    e = (sum(e)/7) * 100
    c = (sum(c)/7) * 100
    name=request.user

    try:
        User=Riasec_result.objects.get(user=request.user)
        Riasec_result.objects.update(user=User,reality=r, investigative=i, artistic=a, social=s,enterprising=e, conventional=c)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        result=Riasec_result.objects.create(user=name,reality=r, investigative=i, artistic=a, social=s,enterprising=e, conventional=c)
        result.save()

    # if (Riasec_result.objects.get(user=name)):
    #     Riasec_result.objects.update(user=name, reality=r, investigative=i, artistic=a, social=s, enterprising=e,
    #                                  conventional=c)
    # else:
    #     result = Riasec_result.objects.create(user=name, reality=r, investigative=i, artistic=a, social=s,
    #                                           enterprising=e, conventional=c)
    #     result.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('riasec:home'))
```

and this is my models.py:

```python
class Riasec_result (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('RIASEC Result')
        verbose_name_plural = _('RIASEC Results')

    user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reality = models.FloatField(null=True)
    investigative = models.FloatField(default=0)
    artistic = models.FloatField(default=0)
    social = models.FloatField(default=0)
    enterprising = models.FloatField (default=0)
    conventional = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), it says:

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
> ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
> will directly return a single object.

So I assume you are trying to assign a couple of `Riasec_result` instances to one instance of the `User` and hence the error.

Comment: or simply remove null value